# NullPointerException to JpaRepository in Spring project on Servlets

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, nullpointerexception

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String login;
private String password;
public User() {

}
public User(String login, String password) {
    this.login = login;
    this.password = password;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
}
```

And i created an interface with annotation @Repository, which looks like:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {


}
```

So, i need to save in my database new users. But, if i use @Autowired UserRepository in my @Service class and call "save" method, it throws me an error 505 with description: HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Cannot invoke "com.example.testservletjsp.repository.UserRepository.save(Object)" because "this.userRepository" is null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.testservletjsp.repository.UserRepository.save(Object)" because "this.userRepository" is null
com.example.testservletjsp.account.UserService.saveUser(UserService.java:28)
com.example.testservletjsp.servlets.ExplorerServlet.doPost(ExplorerServlet.java:68)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:682)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:765)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>test-servlet-jsp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>test-servlet-jsp</name>
<description>test-servlet-jsp</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>

   </plugins>
 </build>
```

What should i do..?

Comment: how do you autowire your field? How did you instantiate your Service class? Do other Spring functionalities (autowire, @Value("") ) work for that Service?

Comment: how can i autowire my field? i marked it as @Autowired

Comment: My Service was marked as @Service and other methods working...

Comment: just because it is marked as @Service is no guarantee it's correctly instantiated

Comment: i shouldnt mark it as service ??

Comment: I didn't say that. But you also have to make sure it's instantiated by the Spring mechanism, and so far we can't tell whether or not that's the case

Comment: So i checked, and if i dont mark service as @service, it doesnt work too..

Comment: but other methods, which dont use repository - working

Comment: again, I didn't say you SHOULDN'T annotate it as a Service. Do those other methods use an autowired field?

Comment: The servlet isn't managed by Spring so no autowiring will take place. Also `@Repository` on that interface is useless. You are using Spring why not use an controller and service instead of a servlet. Or maybe it is but judging from the stacktrace you are doing a `new UserService()` in there. But as there is nothing Spring related in your stacktrace I doubt the servlet is even managed by spring.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As I don't have the entirety of your project I cannot see if there are some miss-configured classes, but you can always visit this (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) spring guide that teaches you all the details you have to keep in mind in order to get that project working.

Comment: That won't work and would lead to a different exception (the app wouldn't even start).

Comment: oh, i have this properties.. but it doesnt work.. :(

Comment: Uhm, understood. Can you share your project via some link? I will look into it and discover what is wrong. And then, update my response.

Comment: Okay, wait a minute, please )

Comment: https://github.com/KAA20Work/servlet-project/tree/main/src .So, i hope that u can help me... :(

Comment: go to your github project, i have opened an issue for you to see.

Comment: after changes i get error: 404 Not Found x) What is it ?))

Comment: It means that the user you are trying to find/update/delete does not exist.

Comment: Or it could mean that the table does not exists. For JPA to work, the name of the table has to be the same as the name of your class

Comment: You can include the annotation `@Table(name = "YOUR_TABLE_NAME")` on `User.java` below the `@Entity` annotation instead of changing the name of your model `User.java`.

Comment: No-no-no, it cant open start page!

Comment: It doesnt open authorizing page.... When i start project, it give me 404 error

Comment: Ahhh got it. In order to make things easier I suggest you to send me some kind of contact communication. StackOverflow does not like when people start talking in this comments, if you want, you can share your contact on the github issue that I opened.

Comment: I send my email as comment on issue.. Kind of like..